# .Net Core Classlib misrequires Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I'm currently on Ubuntu 20.10, when I create Classlib using `dotnet new classlib`, it works as expected. `dotnet build` builds, as `net5.0` **is written** as TargetFramework in csproj file. But when I use `dotnet ef migrations add Init`, following error occures:

Build started...

Build succeeded.

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' was not found.

The following frameworks were found:
3.1.14 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
5.0.5 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

What am I doing wrong? Feel free to stating RTFM (but provide link or direction please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. It is because of `EntityframeworkCore.Design` package. I had to install to proceed further.